# How to identify unknown citation style

Tags: thesis, citation-style

I am in the process of finishing my bachelors thesis and my formal requirements do not name any particular citation style, but instead describe the citation style as following.

Author(s) in the format A. John, B.Doe, C.Miller : Title ; Journal , Publication date, Volume (issue), Page from-to.

In-text citations as author-date.

They recommend the usage of reference manager, endnote, citavi or similar third party software. I have prepared all references in BibTex and I've spent several hours today scouring Mendeley, Citavi et cetera for a suitable format to export to, but seem to be unable to locate a good fit without an actual name of the style.

Is there a good resource (or search engine) to look up such details? I see that citavi offers a search functionality, but this did not yield any result, and I hadn't even input the details like the usage of semicolons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the question is very clear. OP, if you give full details of the citation style including several examples, someone on this site might recognize it.

Comment: This seems rather like a rather unique style. Usually Mendeley's [search by example](https://csl.mendeley.com/searchByExample/) function returns something useful, but not here. Almost all related styles put the year earlier. Have you tried googling for something like 'bibtex style file NameOfYourUniversity'?

Comment: There's good advice here, but you can also just ask your supervisor directly "what is this?" They might say it's someone's personal style car they made and like best, and knowing that will save you time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Author(s) in the format A. John, B.Doe, C.Miller : Title ; Journal , Publication date, Volume (issue), Page from-to.

It does not look similar to any of the common citations styles (APA, MLA, Chicago, etc).

The best way is to list them as text entries in a .bbl file or go for a more sophisticated approach and create a custom style such that the Latex compiler generates references according to your style from the BibTeX file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457310/custom-citation-style-for-custom-document

I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/ would be much more suitable for your question

Answer (score 0):

In light of digital systems for maintaining reference data bases such as Zotero, Endnote, Mendeley etc.and to apply a specific format to references, the request seems outdated. It is of course perfectly reasonable for a university or department to request a certain format but in a digital world it seems backwards to request something that would require a non-standard (name given) format.

It is of course open to the powers that be to decide on any required format of references but it is still quite backwards to require some format that is not a standard unless a format is provided for the digital platform in which you are required to work.

If the grade depends on this format then it is probably best to stick to the instructions, regardless how backwards they may seem. If your work with Word or LateX it is possible to generate a new reference style based along the guide line you are given. I am assuming your are using a refeence manager such as Zotero, Mendeley or EndNote.

So depemnding on your situation, there may be several ways to pursue to avoid too much problems with bureaucracy.